# multiply 2 values from different table using codeigniter and postgresql foreach()

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

Here's the code from my

Controller Page

```
public function table1(){
$this->load->model('test_model');
$data['value']= $this->test_model->getAlltable1();
$data['value2']= $this->test_model->getAlltable0();
$this->load->view('table1', $data);
}
```

Views Page

```
<table class="table">

  <tbody>

<?php   foreach ($value as $v){ ?>
<?php   foreach ($value2 as $v2){ ?>   //different table
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $v->tech_voc?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($v->tech_voc*$v2->tech_voc)?></td>
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The output is somewhat like this

```
1    .75
1    .75
1    .75
1    .75
```

What I want to display is something like this

1    .75

What happen here is that, instead it multiply once, it all multiply each row. And I think it is because I put foreach inside a foreach Please help me.

EDIT
Oh yeah, I already tried deleting the foreach value2
but it says v2 is undefined variable

HOPE it helps.

NEW EDIT:---------------------------------------

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to multiply where the keys are the same (`$value[0]*$value2[0]`, `$value[1]*$value2[1]`, etc) try this.

```
<?php 
$col1_sum = 0;
$col2_sum = 0;
foreach ($value as $k => $v){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $v->tech_voc?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($v->tech_voc*$value2[$k]->tech_voc)?></td>
        <?php //update sums
        $col1_sum += $v->tech_voc;
        $col2_sum += ($v->tech_voc*$value2[$k]->tech_voc);
        ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
<!-- row with sums -->
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $col1_sum?></td>
    <td><?php echo $col2_sum?></td>
</tr>
```

Edited based on comments/chat to include a sum row.

Comment: So what if the keys are not the same?

Comment: Is there something else to match them by? How do you know which ones you want to multiply?

Comment: I add 2 new row but dont have the same keys. After I add the new row, it gets 2 error. First, Undefined offset. Last,  Trying to get property of non-object. All in same page, same line number.

Comment: I dont think they have a match because this new rows will input the sum of each column. Any idea?

Comment: I'm confused. Can you post an example of your tables with the new rows?

Comment: As you can see the picture, there is a result but still have 2 error. As what I understand in your code, so long there's the same key, we could multiply it but here, when I added the 2 new rows, the 2 new rows don't have a match key to the other table.

Comment: What do you want it to do when there is not a matching key? Don't multiply? Multiply by 0? Skip the row?

Comment: well, I want to get the sum above it.

Comment: The sum of all the previous rows?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48691/discussion-between-kino-and-samutz)